# AWS CDK Python (No Credentials Found)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to using the command `CDK Bootstrap` after I have set up my virtual environment using the AWS CDK. This is the code for my application that the command above is pulling credentials from.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from aws_cdk import core

from hello.hello_stack import MyStack


app = core.App()
MyStack(app, "hello-cdk-1", env={'account':'IDHERE','region': 'us-east-2'})
MyStack(app, "hello-cdk-2", env={'account':'IDHERE','region': 'us-west-2'})

app.synth()
```

Obviously I have taken the accountID out. 
When using the command CDK Bootstrap here is my error output

```
 ❌  Environment aws://ACCOUNTIDHERE/us-west-2 failed bootstrapping: Error: Need to perform AWS calls for account ACCOUNTIDHERE, but no credentials found. Tried: default credentials.
    at CredentialsCache.getCredentials (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/util/sdk.ts:261:11)
    at CredentialsCache.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/util/sdk.ts:223:25)
    at SDK.cloudFormation (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/util/sdk.ts:117:20)
    at Object.deployStack (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/deploy-stack.ts:56:15)
    at Object.bootstrapEnvironment (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/bootstrap-environment.ts:93:10)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/bin/cdk.ts:270:24
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
Need to perform AWS calls for account ACCOUNTIDHERE, but no credentials found. Tried: default credentials.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to use using the environment variables:
`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`
`AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`
`AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html

It works for me.

I'm using cdk version `1.57.0`

Answer (score 2):

Did you run `aws configure` at first?
Try to `cat ~/.aws/credentials`, if you see something like everything must be OK:

```
[default]
region = us-east-1
aws_access_key_id = *********************
aws_secret_access_key = ******************************************
```

Or you don't have `aws_access_key_id`/`aws_secret_access_key` in `[default]` section.
All this information you can read here - https://cdkworkshop.com/15-prerequisites/200-account.html (official CDK Workshop).

Comment: So add my access and secret keys to my config?

Comment: Yes, try to do it. I think it will solve your issue.

Comment: It's in there and still not working. Also, i've been following that guide

Comment: Do you have `[default]` profile in credentials, or another name?

Comment: Can you post here your `~/.aws/credentials` and `~/.aws/config`?
Replace secrets by `*`, please.

Comment: [default]
region = us-west-2
aws_access_key_id = *********************
aws_secret_access_key = ************************** .   This is the credentials

Comment: my config is full of company info so I can't do that but, the structure is this                                 [profile name]                                                                                                                        [region]                                                                                                                                       [MFA Serial]

Comment: ok, is there a profile with the name "default"? Or you have another name?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I get temporary credentials using aws-runas and set it using code editor terminal(windows 10).

```
set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=..........
set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=.......
set AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=...........
set AWS_REGION=.......
```

With **code editor terminal** I got the same issue, but with a different **window command prompt**, I able to run bootstrap and deploy commands without any issue.

Answer (score -4):

There was something installed on my root directory that was preventing my node module from executing the cdk. I reimaged my Mac and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: what do u mean by reimaged?

Comment: I want my 10 seconds reading your comment back